# Создание UIView внутри UIScrollView программно

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ув. форумчане, нужна помощь. Как работать с интерфейс билдером, я разобрался, теперь есть задача сделать интерфейс из кода.

Сейчас стопорнулся на небольшой задаче. Нужно реализовать такую иерархию:

```
---- UIView
------ UIScrollView 
--------UIView
```

Основное требование - чтобы все элементы растягивались на весь экран. Проверяю полученное изображение на iPad (10-дюймовый). По этому коду последняя UIView тянется не полностью по вертикали, а при повороте планшета не тянется и по горизонтали.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                                                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];
scroll.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                                                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];

contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[scroll addSubview:contentView];

[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: @Korefey, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Слёту вспомнил несколько вариантов:

1. Для начала советую этот метод. Установить, из кода, всем вьюхам правильные "constraints". Цикл статей по теме:
   [Раз](http://osxdev.ru/blog/ios/76.html), [Два](http://osxdev.ru/blog/ios/79.html), [Три](http://osxdev.ru/blog/ios/84.html).
2. Во ViewController'e реализовать методы, которые вызываются при вращении устройства (нужно смотреть, что там есть у ViewController'a):

   ```
   - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
   - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
   ```

   Внутри пересчитывать размеры вьюх.
3. По сути примерно тоже самое как и второй способ, но реализовать через "NSNotificationCenter", то есть подписаться на уведомления:

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) name:"UIDeviceOrientation***" object:nil];

Comment: Вопрос решен. Применил viewWillLayoutSubviews